# How do I pull the Preferred Vendor of an item to the advanced pdf form of the BOM in Oracle NetSuite?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

We are just starting with Oracle NetSuite and I have been successful in pulling most fields, but some are not pulling over to certain forms/pdfs.

When I go to Advanced PDF/HTML Templates in Oracle NetSuite to edit a Custom Bill of Materials, I am unable to pull the Preferred Vendor's name from the item record on the BOM. I have tried the following with no success...

```
${item.preferredvendor}
${record.preferredvendor}
${item.vendor}
```

and so on...

Does anyone know what this could be?? Is there a site that houses all of the fieldIDs to use in custom PDF/HTML documents?? Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!